# What are the possible reasons a background image will not show in a div

Tags: css

I know this question has been asked several times, but I am unable to find the solution to my problem.  I've been messing around with the code, even entering in JQuery to change the background of this div, but it will not work.  I have a class called "lineuphead" and the following .css

```
.lineuphead{            
    background:#36C;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;

}
```

I have no Jquery or JS editing the class.  Text in .lineuphead displays fine, without any problem.  Changing the div's position, display, z-index, etc, does not fix the problem.  Changing the background image or color does not fix the problem.  You will find the following code at www.progressfestival.com, and the code for the lineuphead just above the lineup for the bands.  I can't figure out what else could possibly be responsible for this .css "malfunction".

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: <div class='lineuphead'></br></br></br></br></br></br></div>

that's the only other part of the code

Comment: Sorry, you haven't included any code that shows a background image, no CSS, no javascript, nothing. If you want our help you need to include the pertinent parts of your code.  Don't link to a site and have us hunt for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a parsing issue with the layout.css file.

At the very top of the CSS file you have an erroneous comment block:

```
  * Skeleton V1.2
  * Copyright 2011, Dave Gamache
  * www.getskeleton.com
  * Free to use under the MIT license.
  * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
  * 6/20/2012
*/
```

You're missing the `/*` from the beginning of the comment block so it should read:

```
/*
  * Skeleton V1.2
  * Copyright 2011, Dave Gamache
  * www.getskeleton.com
  * Free to use under the MIT license.
  * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
  * 6/20/2012
*/
```

See if that solves your problem.

Comment: In fact, there are so many parsing errors where comment blocks have not beed opened/closed correctly. The fact that the class rule `.lineuphead` doesn't show up in the style inspector means this rule is completely redundant. I would suggest you backup your CSS file, make a duplicate and remove all your comment blocks.

Comment: You were right.  There is something wrong with my .CSS.  I moved it up to the top of the document and it works.  Thank you sir!!!

Comment: Or perhaps it was being superseded by some of the other code

Answer (score 0):

Is the element empty? Does it have a `textNode`? The `height` alone won't make an element visible by default, minimally add a text character (like space) or ensure that the element has child elements with content.

Also frameworks are great for getting things done faster but lead to less competent development skills, learning how to code real code will force you to become a better developer and that will increase the demand for your skills if utilized correctly.

Comment: I did that too, I added a ton of </br> to be sure

Answer (score 0):

your class `.lineuphead{}` includes a background color. 
you can do like so.

```
.lineuphead{
background:url("") #36C;
width:"600px";
height:"100px";
}
```

Note that if your `'div'` is empty then you should add some element or text make it visible.

```
<div class="lineuphead">  some content here </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'background-image' property would also be a good option. Check the below link for reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: Tried it, did not help

Comment: I ended up using background-image, but the first 5-10 times I reloaded cache, it did not change anything.  Honestly, I have no idea why it didn't work, but it does now...

Answer (score 0):

Originally, I thought it was a problem with the .CSS.  I did change one open comment, which did not seem to be attached to the .CSS in question.  I moved the .CSS to the top of the document, without changing ANYTHING, and it displayed correctly.  I then added "no-repeat;" and it did not display at all.  This, I believe, would have absolutely no effect on the solid background color I started with in the example.

I honestly have no idea why it started working, but I assure you all that I changed absolutely nothing about the width, size of the div, JQuery/JS, or .CSS.  It literally just magically started working.  I decided to throw out the no-repeat and just change the width/height of the div element to fit it.  That seems to work for no reason at all.